# Parallel Computing In Java

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I make use of parallel in Java? Or do I use normal threads?

Comment: This question is too vague.  If you want meaningful answers, provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).
2. Make multiple threads to do your work for you.

Answer (score -1):

What a big topic!
A typical solution is using multi-threading, you need a class implemented *Runnable* interface and put your function into its run() method. For details, I suggest you buy a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Answer (score -1):

You can use both Java Threads and Java Concurrency framework.

If you are really interested about Java concurrency, [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is a good book to start.